# Controlling order of compilation in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose you have two classes `A` and `B` in two different files `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` respectively, how can you ensure `class A` compiles before `class B`.

Comment: why do you want to do this? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: `gcc A.cpp; gcc B.cpp`.. Is this question about Makefile? and why do you want to enforce that order?? it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I find it frequently helpful to first compile the file I'm currently working on. Sure, others shouldn't need to be recompiled but if I had changed e.g. the header other files are recompiled and may do so even successfully while the file under construction fails (e.g. because the header forgot to include a file which was already included by the other files).

Comment: If this is because you need class A to be defined before class B, you can use forward declarations. Put the line `class A;` above your class B and it will recognize that A exists, even if B is compiled first.

Comment: @AlokSave How about introducing macros from one file to another?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You also should not care, since compilation of different translation units is independent

Comment: it makes a difference when your builds take time!

Comment: @Justin: But why does it matter which order you compile in?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It makes a difference when your builds take a long time because your builds will fail sooner than later -- less idle time for the dev. For example: in large libraries I've written which are dependencies of numerous other projects, I have special translations which compile everything in the library's headers before compiling the library's exports. This immediately ensures the headers compile cleanly, rather than finding out after a few minutes. If that translation succeeds, I can make changes to the lib's cpp files without affecting other translatiions == shorter build times.

Comment: Another reason is that compilation order may define the order of linking, which may then determine the order of initialization for the image's objects which require global construction. So... order is actually important for some projects/systems.

Comment: Yeah, not only does the order in which the linker receives the compilation units matter, also the order in which the preprocessor goes over the code base matters.

This is e.g. important if you calculate a checksum over the binary. Different orders can be different checksums.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum: you confuse, preprocessor is a part of the compiler, it handles each compilation module individually. Now, the order in which linker gets the compiled objects does matter, but, again, it has nothing to do with the order of compilation.

Comment: @valdo You are right. The order with which the preprocessor handles the compilation units shouldn't matter. Even if there's caching, the cache should be invalidated properly. It's the linker where it matters. I'll leave my comment in case someone else is thinking as erroneous as I am.

Answer (score 0):

Use this makefile:

```
x.out: b.o
    g++ a.o b.o -o x.out

b.o: a.o b.cpp
    g++ b.cpp -c

a.o: a.cpp
    g++ a.cpp -c
```

a.cpp will be compiled before b.cpp

Comment: `b.o: b.cpp | a.o` would be better.

Comment: @Olver charlesworth Just trying to learn. What value does the pipeline bring. Is it linux makefile syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to your IDE, or whatever you use to build your program out.

If it were all in headers, you could simply #include A.h in B.h.